# How to make a window always appear at specified location?

Tags: glue42

I created the json file for my WPF C# exe in the config folder. On every subsequent launch it appears in the place I last moved the window.

I want it to always appear at [367, 120].

Is this possible?

Here is my config:

```
{
  "title": "IssueTracker",
  "type": "exe",
  "name": "IssueTracker",
  "details": {
    "path": "C:\\evals\\glue\\IssueTracker\\IssueTracker\\bin\\Debug",
    "command": "IssueTracker.exe",
    "parameters": "",
    "top": 120,
    "left": 367,
    "width": 1000,
    "height": 400
  }
}
```

Comment: why you dont rewrite your config file before closing?

Comment: What has this got to do with C# or WPF?

Comment: This is a glue configuration (https://glue42.com/). I am not able to programmatically manipulate the config file.

Comment: and it is a c# wpf exe app

Comment: Possible?  Yes. You could handle an event ( I think sourceinitialized ) in MainWindow, read your json file and set it's top and left properties.

Comment: In a C#/WPF application you can set the starting location of the application by setting the [WindowStartupLocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.windowstartuplocation?view=netframework-4.8) property of the mainwindow to Manual & set the top & left property to where  you want it to go.

Comment: Thanks! But the glue engine (that the application is in) moves it after it starts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a top level property `ignoreSaveOnClose`, which you can set to `true`.

Seems it slipped from the documentation.

Here's how your config would look like:

```
{
  "title": "IssueTracker",
  "type": "exe",
  "name": "IssueTracker",
  "ignoreSaveOnClose": true,
  "details": {
    "path": "C:\\evals\\glue\\IssueTracker\\IssueTracker\\bin\\Debug",
    "command": "IssueTracker.exe",
    "parameters": "",
    "top": 120,
    "left": 367,
    "width": 1000,
    "height": 400
  }
}
```